# d3.js: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a d3 graph by reading a json object with the method d3.json (). But it does not load, this is because the browser console shows me the following error:

[image]

For this case I am using d3 v3, according to an example I copy from the web.

I would be very grateful if someone could explain me why this error occurs.

Without further ado, I say goodbye gratefully.

Below I leave the complete code of this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-quadtree.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-timer.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-force.v1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(233, 236, 239);">
<br><legend align="center">Convergencia de ODS con Plan Nacional de Desarrollo</legend><hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <script>

            var w = 1200;
            var h = 550;
            var radius = Math.min(w, h);

            var dataset = [
                [ 600, 150]
            ];

            var json = [
                {
                    "pais": "Ecuador",
                    "pais_nid": 14,
                    "ods": "1. Fin a la pobreza",
                    "ods_nid": 35,
                    "ods_color_hex": "E5243B",
                    "objetivos_plan_ods": 5
                },
                {
                    "pais": "Ecuador",
                    "pais_nid": 14,
                    "ods": "2. Hambre cero",
                    "ods_nid": 36,
                    "ods_color_hex": "DDA63A",
                    "objetivos_plan_ods": 9
                }
            ];


            d3.json(json, function(data) {

              var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.objetivos_plan_ods; })])
                  .range([2, 40]);

              //Crear un elemento SVG
              var svg = d3.select("div.jumbotron")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", w)
                  .attr("height", h)
                  .attr("viewBox", "" + -(w/2) + " " + -(h/2) + " " + w + " " + h + "");

              svg.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(dataset)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("r", 125)
                  .attr("stroke", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
                  .attr("stroke-width", "8")
                  .attr("fill", "none");

              svg.on("click", function() {
                  document.getElementById("msg").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
                  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = '';
                  d3.event.stopPropagation();
              });

              var node = d3.select("svg")
                  .append("g")
                  .selectAll("circle")
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("style", "cursor:pointer;")
                  .attr("r", function(d) { return rScale(d.objetivos_plan_ods);})
                  .attr("fill", function(d) {
                      return "rgba(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0) + "," + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0) + "," + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0) + ", 0.50)";
                  })
                  .attr("id", function(d) { return "circle-" + d.ods_nid; })
                  .on("click",function(d) {
                      document.getElementById("msg").removeAttribute("style");
                      document.getElementById("circle-" + d.ods_nid).setAttribute("stroke", "rgb(140, 233, 255)");
                      document.getElementById("circle-" + d.ods_nid).setAttribute("stroke-width", "6");
                      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = d.ods;
                      d3.event.stopPropagation();
                  })
                  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                      document.getElementById("msg").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
                      document.getElementById("circle-" + d.ods_nid).removeAttribute("stroke");
                      document.getElementById("circle-" + d.ods_nid).removeAttribute("stroke-width");
                      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = '';
                      d3.event.stopPropagation();
                  });

              d3.forceSimulation(data)
                  .force("charge", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) { return rScale(d.objetivos_plan_ods); }))

                  .force("r", d3.forceRadial(function(d) { return 125; }))
                  .on("tick", ticked);

              function ticked() {
                  node
                      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
              }

              var color = d3.scale.category20();

              var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                  .value(function(d) { return 5; });

              var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                  .innerRadius(radius - 508)
                  .outerRadius(radius - 480);

              d3.select("svg")
                  .datum(data).selectAll("path")
                  .data(pie)
                  .enter()
                  .append("path")
                  .attr("stroke", "rgb(233, 236, 239)")
                  .attr("stroke-width", "3")
                  .attr("fill", function(d) { return "#" + d.ods_color_hex; })
                  .attr("d", arc);
          })
        </script>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="msg" style="display:none;" class="underline alert alert-warning" align="center"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use a non minimised version of the d3 library to understand what is going on, and then use your browser to trace what is happening

Comment: `d3.json()` is meant for loading external json files.  You can just call the json object within the script like any other variable.

Answer (score 1):

d3.json is a function for getting data by calling external json file. d3.json function is trying to call an external json file and it expect a file path in first parameter. You pass a json data in first parameter and it's invalid for this function. That's why the error occored.

In your case, you don't need to call d3.json. You can remove `d3.json` this function and rename the `json` variable to `data` then it will work well.

If you have any json file instead of data, then you can use the function and you need to pass the file path in first parameter of this function.

Please check the below snippet.

```js
var w = 1200;
var h = 550;
var radius = Math.min(w, h);

var dataset = [
    [ 600, 150]
];

var data = [
    {
        "pais": "Ecuador",
        "pais_nid": 14,
        "ods": "1. Fin a la pobreza",
        "ods_nid": 35,
        "ods_color_hex": "E5243B",
        "objetivos_plan_ods": 5
    },
    {
        "pais": "Ecuador",
        "pais_nid": 14,
        "ods": "2. Hambre cero",
        "ods_nid": 36,
        "ods_color_hex": "DDA63A",
        "objetivos_plan_ods": 9
    }
];


//d3.json(json, function(data) {

  var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.objetivos_plan_ods; })])
      .range([2, 40]);

  //Crear un elemento SVG
  var svg = d3.select("div.jumbotron")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
      .attr("viewBox", "" + -(w/2) + " " + -(h/2) + " " + w + " " + h + "");

  svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 125)
      .attr("stroke", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
      .attr("stroke-width", "8")
      .attr("fill", "none");

  svg.on("click", function() {
      document.getElementById("msg").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = '';
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
  });

  var node = d3.select("svg")
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("style", "cursor:pointer;")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return rScale(d.objetivos_plan_ods);})
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
          return "rgba(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0) + "," + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0) + "," + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0) + ", 0.50)";
      })
      .attr("id", function(d) { return "circle-" + d.ods_nid; })
      .on("click",function(d) {
          document.getElementById("msg").removeAttribute("style");
          document.getElementById("circle-" + d.ods_nid).setAttribute("stroke", "rgb(140, 233, 255)");
          document.getElementById("circle-" + d.ods_nid).setAttribute("stroke-width", "6");
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = d.ods;
          d3.event.stopPropagation();
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          document.getElementById("msg").setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
          document.getElementById("circle-" + d.ods_nid).removeAttribute("stroke");
          document.getElementById("circle-" + d.ods_nid).removeAttribute("stroke-width");
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = '';
          d3.event.stopPropagation();
      });

  d3.forceSimulation(data)
      .force("charge", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) { return rScale(d.objetivos_plan_ods); }))

      .force("r", d3.forceRadial(function(d) { return 125; }))
      .on("tick", ticked);

  function ticked() {
      node
          .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }

  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) { return 5; });

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - 508)
      .outerRadius(radius - 480);

  d3.select("svg")
      .datum(data).selectAll("path")
      .data(pie)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("stroke", "rgb(233, 236, 239)")
      .attr("stroke-width", "3")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return "#" + d.ods_color_hex; })
      .attr("d", arc);
//})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-quadtree.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-timer.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-force.v1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(233, 236, 239);">
<br><legend align="center">Convergencia de ODS con Plan Nacional de Desarrollo</legend><hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="msg" style="display:none;" class="underline alert alert-warning" align="center"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```